# std::array of std::shared_ptr with custom deleter

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to implement a class that manages some shared resources. The number of those resources is know at the compile time and there is a custom action needed to be done just before the resource is released and its destructor invoked. I've decided to go with `std::array<std::shared_ptr<...>>` member and a custom deleter:

```
template <size_t NUM_RESOURCES> class QuirkyMachine {
protected:
    using ResourceDeleter = decltype([](auto resource) { 
        someCustomAction(resource); });
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Resource>, NUM_RESOURCES> _resources;
};
```

Is there a way to make my array to be constructed with `shared_ptr`s that use `ResourceDeleter`, but without explicit construction of each of the pointers and passing it all via some kind of initializer list? I want to use as much standard library as possible, and I need to have a fixed collection with the size known at the compile time.

Comment: Since they're in an array, they'll all be destructed at the same time. In which case, all you really need is one function. Why are you using an array?

Comment: If you're planning on manually calling these when scopes end, then (A) don't do that, use `scope_guard`, and (B) even if you insist, use `std::function`.

Comment: How would you initialize/feed the array?

Comment: _"custom action needed to be done just before the resource is released and its destructor invoked"_ - So you want something to happen when the `use_count` is decreased and not actually just before the destructor is called?  Otherwise, why not do the custom action in the destructor? Sounds like you should create your own shared pointer with callback functionality.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` carries its deleter around with it, so wherever you create the objects for the pointers to point to is where you set the deleter.  You can't just create an empty `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter and then later assign to it and expect the custom deleter to stick around.

Comment: Would `std:unique_ptr` do?  Then the deleter is part of the type.

Comment: If you provide a small self-contained [mcve], I'm sure we could provide a fixed-up version that has the custom deleter behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Suppose you didn't need to use `ResourceDeleter` or anything else special. How would you then initialize `_resources` "without explicit construction of each of the pointers"? `NUM_RESOURCES` instances of `Resource` need to be allocated *somewhere*.

Comment: Why don’t you want an `initializer_list`? You can generate it at compile time using [`index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and various [`...` expansions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), which avoids _“explicit construction of each of the pointers”_, because the compiler “writes” that for you based on `NUM_RESOURCES`.

Comment: As a side note, if possible, I would nest the `shared_ptr` and `array` the other way round. The resources are deleted all at once anyway, together with the `array`. The fewer `shared_ptr`s, the fewer atomic counter operations and the less pointer jumping. (This may be impossible in case you want to transfer co-ownership of the resources outside the `array`’s lifespan, individually for each element.)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just make a class that extends from the std::shared_ptr?
Sth like this:

```
class SharedPtrWithResourceDeleter : std::shared_ptr<Resource> {
    using ResourceDeleter = decltype([](auto resource) { 
        someCustomAction(resource); 
    });
};
```

and then like this:

```
template <size_t NUM_RESOURCES> class QuirkyMachine {
protected:
    std::array<SharedPtrWithResourceDeleter , NUM_RESOURCES> _resources;
};
```

Thats the first thing I would try, but I don't know if it works! (And I haven't now the opportunity to try it)

Comment: How is `declaring nested type ResourceDeleter` going to help anything? If you don't know if it works, don't put your guesses as answers.

Comment: You need to provide constructor and `reset` method to add the custom deleter.